# How do I access Meteor's MongoDB from another client, while Meteor is running?

Tags: python, mongodb, meteor

I would like to access Meteor's MongoDB from a Python client, **while Meteor is running**.

I can't start a mongod because Meteor's database is locked.

How do I access the database from another client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Meteor deployment instructions](http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying)

The command will look like this:

```
   PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp node bundle/main.js
```

Comment: This looks like an answer to a totally different question.

Answer (score 70):

The `meteor` command provides a clean way.  To get the URL for the running mongod:

```
meteor mongo -U
```

which you can parse from python.

Comment: Using the mongo URL provided by `meteor mongo -U <myproj>` for a password protected instance hosted on <myproj>.meteor.com fails with bad authentication.  Am I doing this wrong, is it by design, or is it a bug?

Comment: That command works for password protected sites -- it'll prompt for a password.  If you're getting an auth error from Meteor it thinks there's a password mismatch.

Comment: The URL that comes back is only valid for one minute.  If mongo itself is failing, try getting a fresh URL.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you.  I was able to get my python code to connect.  Now I'm seeing some errors trying to talk to the db, but I'll check on that in a bit.

Comment: I've had some trouble with the URL.  I've created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370681/decipher-an-error-connecting-to-a-mongo-instance-hosted-at-project-meteor-com

Comment: THIS should be the top answer. When port 3002 is used by something else, Meteor will use another port for Mongo. With this command you're able to find out which one is currently used.

Comment: incase you're wondering...the name of the DB is "meteor" (somehow I thought it was the project name)

Comment: @HubertOG: also, if you run `meteor --port NNNN`, the mongo port will be at NNNN+1, not always 3001.

Answer (score 37):

Meteor starts the mongod for you on port 3002 when you run the `meteor` command, and stores the mongo data file in `.meteor/local/db`

Output from `ps aux | grep 'mongod'` shows the mongod command that meteor uses:

```
/usr/local/meteor/mongodb/bin/mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --smallfiles --port 3002 --dbpath /path/to/your/project/.meteor/local/db
```

So just connect your mongo client accordingly.  In python:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> con = pymongo.Connection(host='127.0.0.1', port=3002)
>>> con.database_names()
[u'meteor', u'local']
```

UPDATE: unfortunately making changes directly in mongo in this way won't reflect live in the app, but the changes will be reflected on a full page (re)load.

Comment: According to Derander on the IRC channel this will NOT actually result in live updates to the reactive templates.  He informs me he has tested it, hoping it would work, but was disappointed.

Comment: @Benson - I just tested, and you're right - it updates with a page reload but not live.  My mistake.  I imagine there's probably a way to approximate this behavior (e.g. a re-sync db method you could call periodically in the client), but I don't have time to dig into it right now.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure we could fall back on polling, but that sort of invalidates the whole purpose of meteor -- reactive templates that get updated via the observer pattern.

Comment: Actually, it looks like a full page reload is not required.  In this file - https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js - you will see a refresh timer every 10s regardless of 'dirty' state of Mongo.  Just make update to mongo directly and wait 10s and the change will appear in the browser.

Comment: I just tested this and it does work, you just have to wait 10 seconds for it to be updated. I wish there was a way change the speed of the set interval with out having to dive into mongo-livedata.

Comment: Making live changes happen faster can be tweaked by calling Meteor.refresh({collection:whatev}); in the server code.  I have a snippet of python that lets you trigger this via ZMQ if you are interested.  Also, you could make a document who change/existence trigger a database update, then scan that over and over.

Comment: This answer is way out of date. Writing to Mongo now will cause immediate page updates to all connected servers.

Comment: For me it was port 3001, make sure you run the `ps aux | grep 'mongod'` command to see what port it's using on your machine.

Comment: Yes, they changed the port from 3002 to 3001.

Answer (score 2):

You can also find it from within server side code using:

```
process.env.MONGO_URL
```

Even if you don't set this environment variable when running, it gets set to the default.  This seems to be how it is found internally (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js)

The one is given by `meteor mongo -U` seems to reconstruct the default domain/ip and db-name, but use the port stored in the file.

You can put this anywhere in the server folder, and read it from the command line.

```
console.log('db url: ' + process.env.MONGO_URL);
```

I set up a webpage to display it to double check in the selenium tests that we are using the test database, and not overwriting live data.

Answer (score 0):

And here a shell script to get Mongo URI and Mongo Database:

```
#!/bin/bash -eux

read -s -p "Enter Password: " password

cmd=$(meteor mongo --url myapp.meteor.com << ENDPASS
$password
ENDPASS)
mongo_uri=$(echo $cmd | cut -f2 -d" ")
mongo_db=$(echo $mongo_uri | cut -d/ -f 4)

#my_client_command_with MONGODB_URI=$mongo_uri MONGO_DB=$mongo_db
```

````

Answer (score -1):

In regards to a 10 second delay on updates: Tail the MongoDB oplog! There's more information on how to do it here:

http://meteorhacks.com/lets-scale-meteor.html

Make sure you install smart collections and use those (instantiate your collections using Meteor.SmartCollection instead of Meteor.Collection) and you will find the updates are essentially immediate.

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**