# Decipher an error connecting to a mongo instance hosted at <project>.meteor.com

Tags: python, mongodb, meteor

I'd like to use python to connect to an instance of mongo tied to a meteor app hosted at meteor.com.  I've gotten the URL for my app via the `meteor mongo -U <appname>` command, and I am able to connect.  However, when I have gotten connected and try to do something simple (enumerate documents in the "slides" collection), I get an error:

```
In [1]: import pymongo

In [2]: con = pymongo.Connection("mongodb://client:f066d336-f5bd-1a85-1039-c679fbb645a1@skybreak.member0.mongolayer.com:27017/slides_meteor_com").meteor

In [3]: con.slides.find()
Out[3]: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor at 0x109873690>

In [4]: [ x for x in con.slides.find() ]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationFailure                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/bensonk/Code/lfnw-elite-talk/<ipython-input-4-2112945d50ca> in <module>()
----> 1 [ x for x in con.slides.find() ]

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.pyc in next(self)
    701             raise StopIteration
    702         db = self.__collection.database
--> 703         if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
    704             if self.__manipulate:
    705                 return db._fix_outgoing(self.__data.pop(0), self.__collection)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.pyc in _refresh(self)
    664                               self.__skip, ntoreturn,
    665                               self.__query_spec(), self.__fields,
--> 666                               self.__uuid_subtype))
    667             if not self.__id:
    668                 self.__killed = True

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.pyc in __send_message(self, message)
    626             response = helpers._unpack_response(response, self.__id,
    627                                                 self.__as_class,
--> 628                                                 self.__tz_aware)
    629         except AutoReconnect:
    630             db.connection.disconnect()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.pyc in _unpack_response(response, cursor_id, as_class, tz_aware)
     99             raise AutoReconnect("master has changed")
    100         raise OperationFailure("database error: %s" %
--> 101                                error_object["$err"])
    102 
    103     result = {}

OperationFailure: database error: unauthorized db:meteor lock type:-1 client:173.160.192.81
```

From what I can tell, this is mongo suggesting I don't have access to read from that collection.  I can read from it from a mongo console via `meteor mongo <projectname`, but not from python.  How can I read from it in python?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your database is using authentication and you haven't specified a username/password. In python this is done with `db.authenticate(username, password)`. Details here: http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.1.1/api/pymongo/database.html

Comment: Any idea what the username/password would be for a meteor instance? :-)  This is useful information, but still not an answer to the question as it relates specifically to a meteor instance.

Comment: Actually it looks like you have a username:password in your code sample in the URI (client:f066d336-f5bd-1a85-1039-c679fbb645a1) Can you try connecting using the mongo shell and verify that it's correct?

Comment: I will try that. I've been told that the URI output by meteor mongo <projname> -U outputs a URL that's good for a mere 1 minute, so I'll have to sort that out.  It'll take a bit.