# How is MongoDb installed by Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, razorsql

I'm new to both [Meteor.js](http://docs.meteor.com/#top) and [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and after installing Meteor in the [official way described](http://docs.meteor.com/#quickstart) I wonder how to connect to my MongoDB.

MongoDB was installed by Meteor during the installation and everything works fine but now I would like to have a look into it with another tool (like [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/)) to see what's in there.

But the standard connection parameters (localhost:27017) doesn't work, what can I do? Login? Password?

[image: Connection parameters to MongoDB in RazorSQL]

Comment: Marc, [check this answer out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293781/how-do-i-access-meteors-mongodb-from-another-client-while-meteor-is-running).

Comment: Thank you, I did and couldn't connect with localhost (see my comment to Akshats answer) but with 127.0.0.1 the connection to port 3002 worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update: February 2014 - Meteor 0.7.1 - The meteor port has been shifted to 3001 instead of 3002.** So instead of adding two to the port meteor runs on, you add 1 instead.

MongoDB's database is installed in the meteor package containing your files in a hidden folder called `.meteor`. To access it from a remote tool simply add `2` to whatever your web server port is *while meteor is running*. It will be stored in the *meteor* database

e.g
     `http://localhost:3000` would have its mongodb server running at `mongodb://localhost:3002/meteor` there is no username/password on this instance if you ran it with `meteor` or `meteor run`

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped! Odd behaviour: Meteor has been started with `localhost:3000` but to connect to the MongoDB `localhost` did not work (connection refused) but `127.0.0.1` did. And port number `3002` was correct.

Comment: Be AWARE: The collections may look empty, you would need to make an insert in order to see the data.

Answer (score 5):

To get the Meteor Mongo url and port, first run your Meteor app using `meteor run` then run `meteor mongo` in a different terminal tab. You should see an output like this

```
[meteor-app] meteor mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor
```

this means that your Meteor Mongo is running at `127.0.0.1:3001`.

If you are running your Meteor app with `meteor run` then you neither need username/password nor authentication configuration just make sure that you set your default database name as `meteor`