# Mongodb visualization tool with meteor, can't make it works

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database

I'm running a project locally (localhost:3000) and want to use a tool that let me browse my mongodb database. I tried many of them (mongoview, razorsql, database master, mongoexplorer) and they all seems to be unable to connect to my mongodb database created by meteor locally.

I tried with localhost , 127.0.0.1 , my ip address and with the ports 27017 and 3000 (no username, database name or password) and they all fail to connect. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371926/how-is-mongodb-installed-by-meteor/14373526

Comment: Exactly this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run meteor, mongodb uses the 3002 port :

```
syban@unau:~$ ps -ef | grep mongo
mongodb   1163     1  0 févr.03 ?     00:03:01 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
syban     7701  7683  1 08:33 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/lib/meteor/mongodb/bin/mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --smallfiles --port 3002 --dbpath /home/syban/some_path/.meteor/local/db
```