# How to connect mongodb clients to local Meteor MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How can I connect Robomongo (or any other mongodb client) to the mongodb instance that is created by my local Meteor application?

Comment: Hi @user3330705 if you think the answer is more than useful and that it actually is complete/best, then you can mark it as the accepted answer so that people reading this post will know that it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is MongoDb installed by Meteor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371926/how-is-mongodb-installed-by-meteor)

Comment: I'm on OS X, used robomongo: I just used `localhost` and port `3001` without any authentication for connecting.

Answer (score 123):

Ensure Meteor is running on localhost. Open a terminal window and run `meteor` command. It will  start running on localhost:3000 if you have not changed to port.

While it is running, open a separate terminal window and run `meteor mongo` command. This will open up a MongoDB shell and tell you what port it is connecting to This is normally 3001 as of version 0.7.1.1 or 3002 if earlier. It will say something like `127.0.0.1:3001/meteor`

Go to Robomongo (or your favorite mongodb client software) and create a new connection, making sure to change the connection address to localhost and the given the port number. No need to additionally define /meteor if your client does not insist on a default database.

*Also as pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22023284/1064151 some drivers may need specific line endings, delimeters or other character flow. For example, [ObjCMongoDB](https://github.com/paulmelnikow/ObjCMongoDB) a C based driver wants the url to be `127.0.0.1:3001/` with that extra `/` at the end, or it won't work. So make sure you check the documentation for your driver/client.*

Comment: Im trying the same thing. Im using a mongoDB driver to write to my meteor mongoDB. Before I used `127.0.0.1:3002` like you were saying above. Now I understand that the port has shifted to `:3001` but that address is still not working for me. Did the database name also change? To be more clear, once I connected to my local host `127.0.0.1:3002` I also needed my database name, ie `meteor.collection`. Did this also change with the update?

Comment: Figured it out. Added another answer for a specific mongoDB driver.

Comment: @Nate I just updated the answer to reflect that information. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: It is nice to know about ObjCMongodb and For Robomongo client, It is not necessary to give `/`, I think 3001 is enough , i tested it and it is working fine for me

Comment: This has not worked for me. I am on Windows using Robomongo. My Hosts file contains 192.168.56.111 my-vm and I can connect to my meteor app using http://my-vm:3000, so I know the app is running. When I try to connect using my-vm:3001 it cannot establish a connection - any ideas?

Comment: Does your vm grant access on port 3001? A VM situation is certainly more complicated than a typical local installation.

Comment: If you open RoboMongo on a Mac and don't see anything after connecting, click View => Explorer and then you'll be able to browse connections on the left panel.

Answer (score 36):

Easiest way to get the current configuration details is to use the following command

```
meteor mongo -U
```

This will give you the connection string

Answer (score 31):

From terminal run following command

```
meteor mongo -U
```

That will show you the local host IP address and in which port you application is running. Now run the Robomongo and configure as following two field as you got by running the previous command

[image]

Comment: Connected, but can't see collections. Any idea?

Comment: Same issue - connected but no collections - did you solve?

Answer (score 2):

Use SSH tunneling by the following command :

```
ssh -L 3001:localhost:3001 user-name@host
```

It forwards connections from your local port 3001 to localhost:3001 on your server. Now we can simply connect to our database.

Create a Robomongo connection on your **localhost** and hit **Test** (Out of two checks, Authentication may fail) :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [ObjCMongoDB](https://github.com/paulmelnikow/ObjCMongoDB), a C based mongoDB driver. With the new update instead of using the previous `127.0.0.1:3002` to connect to my localhost running meteor's mongodb, I now need to use `127.0.0.1:3001/` with the collection name still being `meteor.collection`. The important change is the port from `:3002` to `:3001/`. Remember the `/`, it is critical for the connection.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,Before connecting make sure meteor is running.
I am using Robomongo to connect. Create new connection and add
Address as : localhost;
port as: 3001

Answer (score 0):

I'm too using Robomongo and before the latest update V0.7.1,i used  port 3002 to connect,as @Serkan Durusoy suggest's for the latest update it is working for 3001 port

Answer (score 0):

@imal365 answer is perfect. Just to add my insight on it:

I realized that the default Meteor Mongo port number is the port number of the application with 1 added to it (as of version 0.7.1.1). In my case, I was running Meteor on port `1337` with the command `meteor --port 1337` and my Meteor Mongo port was `1338`.