# Rocket.Chat - How get roomId

Tags: rocket.chat

I am new in work with Rocket.Chat. I need send message to channel. I already get authorization. When I read documentation about send message I found roomId parameter, but I don't know how get this ID. I try found in administration panel on Rocket.Chat but without success. Also if who know, how get access to Rocket.Chat database

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to access Rocket Chat from API ?. Rocket Chat stores its data in MongoDB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For accessing the database you can use [Robo 3t](https://robomongo.org/) (how to use it with meteor [How to connect mongodb clients to local Meteor MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020580/how-to-connect-mongodb-clients-to-local-meteor-mongodb)).

Or you can use the [rest api](https://developer.rocket.chat/reference/api/rest-api) to get the channel info https://developer.rocket.chat/reference/api/rest-api/endpoints/core-endpoints/channels-endpoints/info

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using the APIs to send messages, if yes then you will be the one who created the channels (rooms).

When you create a new channel, the response contains details about the newly created channel, which includes the generated `_id`.

In this case, whenever you create a new channel, store it somewhere within your data storage, then restore it using the name of the channel, this will save you a journey to Roekct APIs each time you need to get the roomId.

Answer (score 0):

First, call the API [create-visitor](https://docs.rocket.chat/api/rest-api/methods/livechat/visitor) to create a visitor and in response, you will get a token, use in next API [open-room](https://docs.rocket.chat/api/rest-api/methods/livechat/room) to open a room and in response, you will get room-id.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "msg": "method",
    "method": "createDirectMessage",
    "id": "42",
    "params": ["username-goes-here"]
}
```

use createDirectMessage api, you have to pass usernames of those users you want to create room for. If you don't send any user, a room that have only you will be created.

this api will return roomId of the created room. Below is the response of above api.

```
{
    "msg": "result",
    "id": "42",
    "result": {
        "rid": "room-id-would-be-here"
    }
}
```

Every time you hit createDirectMessage api with same list of users, same roomId will be returned.