# Storing information in meteor mongodb collection from outside nodejs file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I've got a mongodb collection that gets started with Meteor that I would like to connect to and edit from a nodejs file outside of meteor. From my understanding when I start meteor, I can open another terminal and type `meteor mongo` and it allows me to connect to the running mongodb instance that meteor is running. But how can I connect to this from a nodejs file? And add items to a collection in a database? What sort of security/authentication do I have to go through if any? (I don't remember having to set up a username/password for the mongodb, it just starts when meteor starts)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access Meteor's MongoDB from another client, while Meteor is running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293781/how-do-i-access-meteors-mongodb-from-another-client-while-meteor-is-running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running meteor locally, the mongodb is running on port 3001. There's no security or authentication, you simply have to connect to `127.0.0.1` port `3001`, and then access the `meteor` database.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. So if I make a change to a collection from another client, will my view in Meteor update in real time when that change is made?

Comment: Yes sir! Any changes made to Meteor's local database will result in real-time re-rendering of what's on the page.